# Keyboard shortcut to move line up/down in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a shortcut to move a line up/down?

Visual Studio 2010 Productivity Power Tools had this feature, is it built-in on Visual Studio 2012? Is there perhaps a light extension that adds this feature?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found an extension for it: [MoveLine](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b3ee08dc-a28f-4aec-9efa-69215ab5ee52)

> Compatible with VS2012.  Moves a line, or group of lines, up or down
>   in the editor using shortcut keys.  Press the shortcut keys to move
>   the line under the cursor up or down or select a block of text and
>   press the shortcut keys to move the entire block up or down.

The default shortcut keys are as follows:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑ (Up Arrow)</kbd> – Moves a line up
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓ (Down Arrow)</kbd> – Moves a line down

To change the shortcut keys:

- In the Visual Studio main menu go to Tools → Options
- Expand Environment
- Select Keyboard
- In the Show commands containing box type `Tools.MoveLineUp` or `Tools.MoveLineDown`
- In the Press shortcut keys box press the new shortcut keys
- Click Assign

Comment: For VS2013, it looks like this functionality is in [LineMan](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/92ef7620-d7f6-493f-825a-ba52d07d56c2)

Comment: For VS Community 2019, looks like this functionality is built in.

Comment: For clarification, the 2019 Visual Studio built in functionality also uses Alt UpArrow and Alt DownArrow.

Answer (score 11):

### Update Visual Studio 2013+

VS 2013+ should have this editor action built in - if you want to assign keybindings, go to:

1. Tools > Options > Keyboard
2. Search for the commands:

   ```
   Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp
   Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown
   ```
3. Set the shortcut keys in "Text Editor" scope

[image: example]

**See Also**: [What's the equivalent for eclipse's ALT+UP/DOWN (move line) in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4526715/1366033)

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> moves the current line down.
Look for "Edit.LineTranspose" in [Pre-defined Keyboard Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This moves the line down, but I guess there isn't a way to move up. +1 anyway